# Sybase Select Statement

Tags: sql, select, sybase

I am trying to select with some specific conditions but cannot seem to get what I am wanting.

Table Person
person_id | first_name | last_name

Table Service
service_id | person_id | start_time | end_time | service_type_id

Table Service_Types
type_id | description

Table Service_User
service_id | start_time | end_Time | user_id

The goal is to get all of the person_id's that meet any of the following criteria:

1. Last Name Like 'Mar%'
2. Service Type Like 'Fusions%'
3. Service Type Like 'New%' And User_Id = 'Bob' And Start_Time On Or After 2009-01-01

Here's the statement I have been trying to use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT person_id FROM person P,service S, service_types ST, service_user SU WHERE P.person_id = S.person_id AND S.service_id = SU.service_id AND ST.type_id = S.service_type_id AND (P.last_name LIKE 'Mar%' OR ST.description LIKE 'Fusions%') OR (ST.description LIKE 'New%' AND SU.user_id = 'Bob' AND start_time >= '2009-01-01')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your  last condition should be

```
AND ((P.last_name LIKE 'Mar%' OR ST.description LIKE 'Fusions%') 
OR (ST.description LIKE 'New%' AND SU.user_id = 'Bob' AND start_time >=  2009-01-01'))
```

Comment: Ok now how would I select all columns from person without having to type each individual column name out, I only listed 3 there are about 98.

Comment: @t2nator `SELECT P.*`.

Comment: There is a column in person : parent_id which links to the person table. How could I retrieve the parent_id rows for the persons that don't have there own id set as parent_id?

Comment: Do a self JOIN on `parent_id` attribute of the table.

Comment: @t2nator, did this answer your question? If so, you should mark it as the answer so others with the same question will know, and also so more people will be willing to answer your other questions.