# Sybase Select Statement With Table Constraints

Tags: sql, sybase

I am trying to select with some specific conditions but cannot seem to get what I am wanting. I have the following tables:

Person 
`person_id | first_name | last_name | prim_parent_id | sec_parent_id`

Service 
`service_id | person_id | start_time | end_time | service_type_id`

Service_Types 
`type_id | description`

Service_User 
`service_id | start_time | end_Time | user_id`

The goal is to get all of the `person_id` that meet any of the following criteria:

```
Last Name Like 'Mar%'
Service Type Like 'Fusions%'
Service Type Like 'New%' And User_Id = 'Bob' And Start_Time On Or After 2009-01-01
```

Here is the statement thus far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT person_id
FROM person P, service S, service_types ST, service_user SU
WHERE P.person_id = S.person_id 
  AND S.service_id = SU.service_id 
  AND ST.type_id = S.service_type_id 
  AND ((P.last_name LIKE 'Mar%' 
        OR ST.description LIKE 'Fusions%') 
    OR (ST.description LIKE 'New%' 
        AND SU.user_id = 'Bob' 
        AND start_time >= '2009-01-01'))
```

With the above statement working I also need the rows that match the `prim_parent_id` and `sec_parent_id` from the above results.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sybase Select Statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21123140/sybase-select-statement)

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what's being asked here. Are you trying to pull back more rows (ie people whose last name doesn't begin with Mars, but their parents do) or pull back more columns (for given result set, display first names of both parents).

If the former, just use UNION of 3 separate queries.

If latter, use JOIN as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    P.person_id,
    prim_parent_id,
    sec_parent_id
FROM
    person P,
    person parent1,
    person parent2,
    ...etc...
WHERE
    P.person_id = S.person_id and
    P.prim_parent_id = parent1.person_id and
    P.sec_parent_id = parent2.person_id and
    ...etc...
```